# Проблема повторной отправки данных из формы в MVC

Tags: mvc, php

Сайт построен по MVC, и есть страница авторизации у неё есть контроллер, и при правильной авторизации человек кидает на закрытую страницу, а при не правильной в контроллере формируется сообщение об ошибке типа: "Неправильный логин или пароль" и сразу печатается во View, теперь вопрос, если человек нажмет f5 и будет повторная отправка формы, избежать отправки можно редиректом на эту страницу, но тогда сообщение об ошибке не будет показано, так как переменная не определена, думал может записать сообщение об ошибке в сессию, это нормальный выход из ситуации, или есть что-то получше?

Answer (score 3):

Используйте защитный механизм против мультипоста.

Как вариант:
В начале скрипта генерируем некую кракозябру, например:

```
$_GLOBALS['AUTH_KEY'] = substr(md5(time().rand(9000,999999)),5,10);
```

и пихаем эту переменную в формы:

```
echo '<input type="hidden" name="auth_key" value="'.$_GLOBALS['AUTH_KEY'].'"/>';
// или через темплейту, в общим не важно как мы её выведем, главное что бы это попало в форму.
```

В конце скрипта в сессию записываем наш ключ что мы сгенерили.

Когда мы обрабатываем сабмит формы, то значение в сессии и $_REQUEST['auth_key'] должны совпадать, если это не так, то это мультипост ( вторая отправка ) и мы игнорируем этот запрос.

Answer (score 2):

Да, это нормально это называется flash сообщения. Ты записываешь сообщение в сессию, затем выводишь и сразу удаляешь. Так это должно работать.

Comment: этот механизм используется в некоторых фреймворках и считаю он достаточно продуманный. Посмотрите как он реализован в Yii к примеру